# djangoproject access fields of object dynamically

Tags: python, django

Can anyone help me?

I have list of fields called 'allowed_fields' and I have object called 'individual'.
allowed_fields is sub set of individual. Now I want to run loop like this

for field in allowed_fields:
          obj.field = individual.field

obj have same fields like individual. Do you have solution of my problem? I will thankful to you.

Comment: fields in allowed_fields are strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each `field` is actually a string, you could try the following.
I renamed `field` to `fieldname` to better indicate that it is a string.

```
for fieldname in allowed_fields:
    setattr(obj, fieldname, getattr(individual, fieldname))
```

Answer (score 0):

setattr(obj, fieldname, fieldvalue)

(see also getattr to retrieve at runtime)